# ros node not working when using launch file

Tags: ros, roslaunch, roslauch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Similar issue has been addressed in these two questions before [hello node](http://answers.ros.org/question/11302/why-roslaunch-couldnt-show-the-ros_info-message/) and [output roslaunch](http://answers.ros.org/question/9473/how-can-i-get-my-cout-output-on-the-console-with-roslaunch/). But I cannot get my node to work through the launch file. If I run the node like this:

```
./image_listener_test_node
```

it works everything is printed correctly. However through the launch file:

```
<launch>
    <node name="image_listener_test" type="image_listener_test_node" pkg="image_listener_test"  output="screen"/>

</launch>
```

Nothing is printed and no error message. Is there something else I am missing?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/240668/ros-node--not-working-when-using-launch-file./) by [jtim](https://answers.ros.org/users/27497/jtim/) on ROS Answers with karma: 153 on 2016-07-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I figured it out. It was sourcing that was the issue. This means an old project file of the node existed a different place. So when running rosrun or roslaunch they found the old version. and when I executed I had the correct version. Deleting all Devel and build folders in my folder solved it.

---

Originally posted by [jtim](https://answers.ros.org/users/27497/jtim/) with karma: 153 on 2016-08-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you tried using rosrun? That is, you should be able to start the node from the command line using "rosrun image_listener_test image_listener_test_node". If you can't do that, it won't work from roslaunch. If the rosrun command doesn't work, you probably have not installed the node correctly from CMakeLists.txt. Following the pattern in the ROS tutorials, I use something like this:

```
catkin_install_python(
    PROGRAMS
        nodes/image_listener_node
    DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION})
```

(There may be another way to do it by installing the whole nodes/ directory, but I haven't found it yet.) You'll need to run "catkin_make", of course. (Once you run it once, I think rosrun will find it from the package directory, so you don't have to run "catkin_make" after every edit while you're developing.)

---

Originally posted by [Mark Rose](https://answers.ros.org/users/27558/mark-rose/) with karma: 1563 on 2016-08-02

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1